# If a sequence of real numbers converges to 1, then what do we say about its reciprocal?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose the sequence of real number  $\lbrace x_n \rbrace _{n=1}  ^{\infty}$ converges to 1,     $x_n \neq 0 \; \; \; \forall n=1,2,3,...$. Show that $\lbrace \frac{1}{x_n} \rbrace _{n=1}  ^{\infty} $ converges to 1 using episilon-delta definition.

Hint: If the sequence of real number  $\lbrace x_n \rbrace _{n=1}  ^{\infty}$ converges to $B \in \mathbb{R} | \lbrace 0 \rbrace $, and if $x_n \neq 0 \; \; \; \forall n=1,2,3,...$ then
            1. $\lbrace \frac{1}{x_n} \rbrace _{n=1}  ^{\infty} $ converges to $\frac{1}{B}$

2. $\vert x_n \vert > \frac{\vert B \vert }{2}$ for some $n>N$

These were my thoughts to prove this idea: If the sequence of real number  $\lbrace x_n \rbrace _{n=1}  ^{\infty}$ converges to $1 \in \mathbb{R} | \lbrace 0 \rbrace $, and if $x_n \neq 0 \; \; \; \forall n=1,2,3,...$ then  given an $\epsilon > 0$ there exist an $ N \in \mathbb{ Z} ^{+}$ such that $\vert x_n -1 \vert < \epsilon $ whenever $n>N$.

But we know that $\vert x_n -1 \vert= \vert 1 - x_n \vert =\geq  \vert 1  \vert - \vert x_n \vert=  1-\vert x_n  \vert   $

It therefore follows that  $ 1-\vert x_n  \vert < \epsilon $ whenever $n>N$.

Now choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, then we have $ 1-\vert x_n  \vert < \frac{1}{2} $ whenever $n>N$ from this we have $ \vert x_n  \vert > \frac{1}{2} $ whenever $n>N$

From here one can proceed as pewani has given below: that is why I accepted his answer below...

Please open this answer don't close it.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Might help to note that convergent sequences are bounded.

Comment: I tried similar way as Pewani's answer below. And it works. Good luck.

Comment: Guys tell me why you are down voting this que?

Comment: Please reopen this question. I have verified that and the answer given by pewani below is 100 percent correct. Read K.G. Binmore for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\lbrace x_n \rbrace$ converges to $1$, then given $\epsilon > 0 $, there exists an $N > 0$ such that $\vert x_n -1 \vert<  \epsilon  $ whenever $n > N$.

Now we assume that $x_n \neq 0$, then $\vert x_n  \vert  > \frac{1}{2}$

and hence $\displaystyle  \vert \frac{1}{x_n} -1 \vert=\vert \frac{1-x_n}{x_n} \vert <2 \vert 1-x_n  \vert < 2 \epsilon  $

Hahaha, this is one of the sweetest proofs, hahaha